# Object gets stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to approach just a simple idea of OOP but its been a while since I used something like this.

```
class UserAPI
{
    protected $Email;
    protected $APIKey;
    public function setEmail($e)
    {
        $this->Email = $e;
        return (new UserAPI)->setEmail($this->Email);
    }
    public function setKey($k)
    {
        $k = hash('SHA256',$k);
        $this->APIKey = $k;
        echo 'Key Wrote';
        return (new UserAPI)->setEmail($this->Email)->setKey($this->APIKey);
    }
    public function getVals(){ echo 'Vals wrote;'; return array('key' => $this->APIKey, 'email' => $this->Email); }
}

print_r((new UserAPI)->setEmail('Example')
        ->setKey('Password')
        ->getVals());
```

As you can probably gather, the `(new UserAPI)->setEmail('...')` will get stuck in an infinite loop - and so will, eventually, the `setKey()`; I have been stuck on this for ages and cannot figure out how to return the new Object for continued use.

Any help would be perfect.

Comment: setEmail is in recursion .

Comment: Why `UserAPI` creates a new instance of `UserAPI` when calling `setEmail()`?

Comment: Why don't you just return `$this`?

Comment: The idea is to be able to, like magento does, let people use the Object as it changes by returning the current Object properties for further additions.

Comment: return (new UserAPI)->setEmail($this->Email); is in infinite recursion ! for which either you should have a termination condition or return $this as suggested by Mark Baker

Comment: Yes, I established that its infinite in the post, I just didn't know how to return its current properties and new there was something I was forgetting since never before did I have to state its method twice. Appreciated though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `$this->` inside the class to reference the object itself, and create a new object with `new UserAPI()`.

```
class UserAPI
{
    protected $Email;
    protected $APIKey;
    public function setEmail($e)
    {
        $this->Email = $e;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setKey($k)
    {
        $k = hash('SHA256',$k);
        $this->APIKey = $k;
        echo 'Key Wrote';
        return $this;
    }
    public function getVals(){ 
        echo 'Vals wrote;'; 
        return array('key' => $this->APIKey, 'email' => $this->Email); 
    }
}

// this...
$u = new UserAPI();       // create object
$u->setEmail('Example');  // set e-mail
$u->setKey('Password');   // set password
print_r($u->getVals());   // get values

// ...is equivalent to this...
$u = new UserAPI();           // create object
print_r(
    $u->setEmail('Example')   // set mail
    ->setKey('Password')      // set password
    ->getVals());             // get values
// ...but only where the class methods return the object
// (ie. not for getValues())
```

You can propagate the class to another derived call by just returning `$this`.

But then,

Comment: Thats perfect! I knew there was something dodgy about having to run methods twice, this works. Thanks alot! - will mark it when i can

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. yw.